# Why is Jekyll returning the wrong data record?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to add data from a `.csv` file in my `_data` folder to a page, but Jekyll keeps returning information from the record *after* the one I'm trying to retrieve.  Why?  For example, my page has a field called `object_ID` that I pass via a Liquid `assign` tag, but the value returned corresponds to the n+1th `object_ID` from my data file.

If I understand the Jekyll Data Files doc correctly, I don't think I need to add any `csv_reader` options to my `_config.yml`.

Here's the contents of the page on which I'd like to use the data:

```
---
objective_ID: 7
---

Some page contents here
```

Here's the contents of the data file:

```
objective_ID,title,latitude,longitude,elevation,prominence,isolation
   ...
7,"Royal Lake","47.83192","-123.21074","5121",,
8,"Grand Lake","47.89029","-123.34488","4737",,
   ...
```

Here's the contents of the layout file I'm using for my page:

```
---
layout: default
---
The page ID is {{ page.objective_ID }} <br>
{% assign objective = site.data.objectives[page.objective_ID] %}
The objective dict is {{ objective }}
```

And, finally, here's the output that's being rendered to the page:

```
The page ID is 7
The objective dict is {"objective_ID"=>"8", "title"=>"Grand Lake", "latitude"=>"47.89029", "longitude"=>"-123.34488", "elevation"=>"4737", "prominence"=>nil, "isolation"=>nil}
```

In this example, I'm on a page with an `object_ID` of 7, I want to get the corresponding info from my data table for an `object_ID` of 7, but instead, I'm getting the table data for an `object_ID` of 8.  Why?

Comment: I think part of the answer is that csv is strings, and the value I'm passing from my page is an integer.  If I wrap the `object_ID` on my page in quotes, things suddenly work.  This isn't ideal; I don't want to go through each page, and wrap that one number in quotes. But I've tried adding the `integer` csv converter to my `config`, and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Try inspecting the `objectives` object by jsonifying into a `pre` element: `<pre>{{ site.data.objectives | jsonify }}</pre>`. Rendering this sample will inform you if the entries are as you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `site.data.objectives[7]` returns row 8 of your data file not including the headers. The starting index of the rows is 0 and I can presume your `objective_ID` column start at 1.

To fix this you could have your first ID as 0 rather than 1, but then you would have to change every page where you use `objective_ID` and decrease it by 1.

Another fix could be to do:

```
---
layout: default
---
The page ID is {{ page.objective_ID }} <br>
{% assign objective = {{ site.data.objectives | where:"objective_ID", page.objective_ID }} %}
The objective dict is {{ objective }}
```